# Find which application launched my Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Other applications can select files from my app.

```
 <activity
            android:name="xxxx"
            android:icon="@drawable/xx"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_secure_cloud_drive_file_chooser" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I send back the file to the requested app

```
result.setData(uri);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
```

everything is working fine.
Now i need to know who is calling my application? e.g. (mail, dropbox ... etc)

i tried `getCallingActivity()` it did not work always returns `com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity`

can anyone help me find it. I'm using lollipop so the getTask trick won't work.
HELP !

Answer (score -1):

Use `getCallingActivity().getClassName()`